# How to create user subscriber in aweber?

Tags: aweber

Anyone can help ,

I have created an api key and and secret key but I am getting an issue regarding to the login section means the api redirect to the  https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize_app/ url and here need a username and password but I am inserting my username and password but its not open and send me a message like

**Notice: Invalid credentials - please retry**

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're using valid AWeber credentials when filling out that form. The username/password are not the API developer account from https://labs.aweber.com, but an actual AWeber account (i.e. what you would use to login to https://aweber.com).